# My catch block is being ignored

Tags: sql, powershell, try-catch

I have list of 400 IP addresses to query, but it only outputs 324.

Troubleshooting shows that database transactions are stuck in catch{} block.

For some reason, it isn't outputting the code, "No data for $k"

How else to troubleshoot?

```
foreach ($k in $file_line){


    $SQL = "SELECT ...
    AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '$k'"


    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQL,$conn)

    $start = Get-Date
    do{
        try{
            $rdr = $NULL
            $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()


            while ($rdr.read()){
                $sql_output += ,@($rdr.GetValue(0), $rdr.GetValue(1), $rdr.GetValue(2), $rdr.GetValue(3), $rdr.GetValue(4), $rdr.GetValue(5),$rdr.GetValue(6))

            }
            $transactionComplete = $true

        }
        catch{

            $transactionComplete = $false
            if (((Get-Date)-$start).TotalSeconds -gt 5) {
                Write-host "No data for $k"
                $transactionComplete = $true
            }

        }

    }until ($transactionComplete)

}
```

Comment: Perhaps it didn't hit the catch block because it didn't error.  Did you try running your query in the database and see how many results come back?

Comment: @Siyual ---- I entered in a list of IP addresses, the loop iterates through it. At one point, I even printed out all SQL statements --- there were 400 of them, yet only 324 got executed .... 76 are unaccounted for.

Comment: try catch only works for terminating errors.

Comment: Might be what Matt said. Try adding `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to debug your script using Powershell ISE or a similar tool which enables you to set breakpoints and step through your script.

```
powershell_ise.exe
```

For instructions on how to debug in Powershell ISE have a look at:

https://technet.microsoft.com/de-at/library/dd819480.aspx